# Animating ModelEntity along the edges of detected reference image in ARImageTrackingConfiguration

Tags: realitykit

I am trying to make an animation in Swift & RealityKit that when a reference image is detected (using `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`), we would create a sphere entity...

```
func createSphere() -> ModelEntity {
    let sphere = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.01)
    let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: true)
    return ModelEntity(mesh: sphere, materials: [material])
}
```

and then I would like the sphere to animate and basically move along the perimeter of the detected image and loop infinitely. This is the part that I unfortunately, don't know how to do.

I suppose since we're using ARImageTrackingConfiguration and therefore work in 2D space, I could get the corners of the reference image like this:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { continue }
        let halfWidth = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width / 2
        let halfHeight = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height / 2

        // Corner positions
        let topLeft = SIMD3(-halfWidth, 0, -halfHeight)
        let topRight = SIMD3(halfWidth, 0, -halfHeight)
        let bottomLeft = SIMD3(-halfWidth, 0, halfHeight)
        let bottomRight = SIMD3(halfWidth, 0, halfHeight)
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to continue and how to use this to make the sphere move between these points.